# The characteristic of a quasilinear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I have the equation
$$(y^2-u^2)u_x -xyu_y = xu$$
with the initial condition $u(x, x) = x$. I managed to write down the characteristic
$$\frac{dx}{y^2-u^2} = \frac{dy}{-xy} = \frac{du}{xu}.$$
After some manipulations on the equation
$$\frac{dy}{-xy} = \frac{du}{xu},$$
I got
$$yu = c_1$$
for some constant $c_1$.

However, I couldn't manage to derive anything about $c_2$, the other constant which will show up in the solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Can you think about multipliers?

$\frac{xdx+y{dy}}{xy^2-xu^2-xy^2} = \frac{du}{xu}$

$\implies xdx+ydy+udu=0$

Comment: How could I miss that? The solution now is obvious, thank you!